# How to move all elements of PageLayout to left (right, right, up, down..) 5 cm (C#)?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

Are there anyone know how to move all element (text, line,) of a PageLayout (in GraphicsContainer) to left (or right, up...) 5 cm using C# ?

Comment: ArcObjects documentation is pretty good for this purpose, will explain everything in details. Loop trough the elements in container GraphicContaineer.Next() an use ITransform2D interface on each element, than use .Move().

Comment: @taibc, This link gives an example of the ITransform2D.Move method how all elments may be moved, http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/b6d71738-1055-440d-8e36-14fc9cf1e23a.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments [ITransform2D.Move](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003w4000000) on the elements is the way to go.

Remember that the [IPageLayout.Page.Units](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000nq5000000) can be different from centimeters though. The layout elements transformation methods take arguments in page units. You can use the [UnitConverter](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0042000002rq000000) class to convert between units in a generic way.